# Excel 2010: How to rearrange a column into a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to invert columns and rows in a part of my worksheet: columns should become rows and vice-versa.

How can I easily do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy/paste special and check "Transpose" when you paste.
Well explained here : http://www.ehow.com/how_13014_paste-special-command.html

Btw, if you want to do it by formula, you can use the TRANSPOSE formula.
Well explained here : http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/transpose.php

Comment: Great. The only thing is that Transpose doesn't appear in the menu unless you're copy/pasting from the same Excel instance, which I'm not doing. Workaround: Paste in the other instance, then copy from there and paste again. This time, the transpose option appears.

Comment: Thanks for adding this tip (i forgot that point). Btw, if this does answer your question, you can accept the answer.